# Spring Data Rest and excerpt Projections

Tags: spring, rest

I am using the inlineAddress sample of the Spring Data Rest documentation.

/persons return the address inline as expected.

Now I add a projection to the AddressRepository

```
@RepositoryRestResource(excerptProjection = AddressProjection.class)
```

Which is as below

```
@Projection(name = "AddressesProjection", types = Address.class)
public interface AddressProjection {

public String getStreet();
}
```

This is causing the /persons call to have an address projection as _embedded

```
    {
      "_embedded" : {
        "persons" : [ {
           "firstName" : "dfdf",
           "lastName" : "2",
           "addresses" : [ {
            "street" : "tx",
         "state" : "tx",
        "country" : "dfd"
      } ],
      "_embedded" : {
        "addresses" : [ {
          "street" : "tx",
          "_links" : {
            "self" : {
              "href" : "/api/addresses/1{?projection}",
              "templated" : true
            }
          }
        } ]
      },
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : " api/persons/1{?projection}",
          "templated" : true
        },
        "addresses" : {
          "href" : " /api/persons/1/addresses"
        }
        }
       } ]
     }
   }
```

I dont know if this is expected.  This behaviour is causing repeated information when I have a oneToMany relation like order/Comments and have projection on both order and comments and when I access order/1/comments I see the order also embedded for each comments.

Comment: Could you post your versions? (SDR, SF, etc)

Comment: Spring Boot v1.2.5.RELEASE, Spring v4.1.7.RELEASE

Comment: Was this ever resolved? I am running into the same problem, especially with the oneToMany problem of repeating

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar issue with `spring-data-rest 2.5.6`. So I'd like to add this.

**If** :

- an A entity has a `@OneToMany` relationship to a B entity
- the B entity's repository `@RepositoryRestResource` contains an excerptProjection

**Then** spring-data-rest will embed the B entity's list in any A entity (in _embedded).

If there is no `excerptProjection`, the list won't be embedded.

I'd like to be able to choose what I want to be embedded, but at moment, I found no solution to do so.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody that is looking for the answer to this issue, I actually did find a solution.

Based on the example in [Spring-RestBucks](https://github.com/odrotbohm/spring-restbucks/blob/master/server/src/main/java/org/springsource/restbucks/order/web/CoreOrderResourceProcessor.java) you will need to have a custom `RepresentationModelProcessor` on `A entity`.

Also consider the official [Spring HATEOAS Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/reference/html/#server.processors) on `RepresentationModelProcessor`.

Applying to the above example, you would do:

```
public class PersonRepresentationProcessor implements RepresentationModelProcessor<EntityModel<Person>> {

  private final EntityLinks entityLinks;

 @Override
 public EntityModel<Person> process(EntityModel<Person> personModel) {
  // create new EntityModel without the embedded collection

  TypedEntityLinks<Person> typedPersonLink = entityLinks.forType(Person::getId);

  EntityModel<Person> newPerson = new EntityModel<>(personModel.getContent(),
                                                    personModel.getLinks());

  // add more links or other modifications
  return newPerson;
 }
}
```